# jQuery function transform my parameters to int

Tags: php, jquery, function, types, parameters

My function transforms the parameter string to int.

I've a string variable in PHP, in php I call a test(variable) function, which is a jQuery function (in other file).
When I show the variable in the function, get an int variable.
Example:

**File .php**

```
$ids="304620,306408";
echo '<script>article('.$ids.');</script>';
```

**File jQuery**

```
function article(ids){
 alert(ids);  *//show 304620 only*
 alert(jQuery.type(ids)); *//show number*
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Because comma make it pass 2 params to `article()` method: `article(304620,306408)` You could pass an array or a string but that depends what you are expecting here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quote your string while passing to function `article()`

```
$ids="304620,306408";
echo '<script>article("'.$ids.'");</script>';
```

Comment: yup, but i just fixed small mistake in OP's code :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show 2 values in your jQuery function,Try passing an array from php into the jQuery function.

Secondly,By Default jQuery is changing the php's string value into a number datatype,
So you could simply type cast your jQuery number variable into a string.